# Workflows not working for sending mail to a Group under Sharepoint Appstep

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow created using App Step and I am able to send the mail for a particular user, but when I try to send the mail for a group the workflow gets cancelled and returning the error as:

> RequestorId: e2e82bc4-4c1f-b170-af9b-f98ba870f7f6. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["31"],"SPRequestGuid":["3743add9-0c59-4341-af5a-03bb570526cf"],"request-id":["3743add9-0c59-4341-af5a-03bb570526cf"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4701"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0,
>   private"],"Date":["Thu, 21 Jul 2016 11:42:18
>   GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={398aa3b9-3eed-448c-89b6-07651a321a9e};
>   path=/"],"WWW-Authenticate":["NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)*

But the workflow is running as expected outside the App Step even for SharePoint group.I am not understanding where I have missed.

Comment: Is that and AD group or SharePoint group?

Comment: It is a sharepoint group

Comment: Then it should be cancelled. As per my knowledge the Workflow Send Email tries to find the email address of the specific user. While sending email to a group do not provides a valid email address and a valid user type. Try creating an AD group and then add all the target users in that group. Give it a try sending email to that security group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send mail to the SharePoint group. 
You can send mails only to users and distribution group(AD group).

Hope this helps.